# Feign masking OAuth2 OAuth/token spring boot

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, feign

I'm trying to mask oauth/token the token generation through feign client port but not with oauth server port. I have added my request interceptor.

But when I'm trying to generate token I'm getting 406 not acceptable as below :

[image: But when I'm trying to generate token I'm getting 406 not acceptable]

Can someone please post a solution ?

```
public class UserFeignClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = "Bearer";

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            System.out.println("details " + details.getRemoteAddress());
            System.out.println("details " + details.getSessionId());
            System.out.println("details " + details.getTokenType());
            System.out.println("details " + details.getTokenValue());
            System.out.println("details " + details.getDecodedDetails());
            template.header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, String.format("%s %s", BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE, details.getTokenValue()));
        }
    }
}
```